# How to remount a component on action from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

both of these components are child component of *Home.js* and what I want is on onSubmit in StudentCreateComponent, ListStudentComponent to mount again and fetch data, and render without refreshing the page.

Here's my **StudentCreateForm** component submit.

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 axios
  .post("http://localhost:8000/api/", data)
  .then((response) => console.log(response.data));
};
```

and here's my **ListStudent** component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/")
      .then((response) => setStudents(response.data));
  }, []);
```

Comment: I think there are 2 ways. One of them is that you can create a common variable on Home.js and then when you take the common data with the props, you can create a data pipe between child components. The second way is that you can use a global management system as such redux. You add a global state variable and when you change the variable, you can want to render any component drastically by setting the data on dependencies. But I think the second way is better than that.

Comment: You could pass a prop from StudentCreateForm that will change when it fetch, to ListStudent and add it in the useEffect dep array. So, when the first fetch is finished it will trigger the ListStudent  effect to run again